# Identify the extreme points and extreme directions of $S = \{x : 4x_2 \geq x_1^2, x_1 +2x_2 + x_3 \leq 2\}$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Identify the extreme points and extreme directions of $S = \{x : 4x_2 \geq x_1^2, x_1 +2x_2 + x_3 \leq 2\}$

Which I specifically need help finding the extreme directions.

The extreme points are defined by the intersection of the two defining constraints of $S$. With this in mind, I have found equations of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $x_3$ that represent the extreme points of $S$.

They are

$$x_1 = -1 \pm \sqrt{1-2x_3}$$

$$x_2 = \frac{3-x_3 \mp \sqrt{1-2x_3}}{2}$$

where $x_3 \leq \frac{1}{2}$

I just don't really have a clue on how to find the extreme directions from here.

These are the definitions I have from my professor:

[Extreme Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtL0g.png)

[Directions/Extreme Directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij85K.png)

[Characterization of Extreme Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWMae.png)

[Characterization of Extreme Directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsXdG.png)

He usually doesn't give any examples, just usually the definitions and theorems for concepts.

So looking at these equations and sketching out $S$, definitely tells us that $S$ is bounded in the positive $x_3$ direction. Therefore if we have a extreme direction $d = (d_1, d_2, d_3)$, then it must be that $d_3 < 0$. Which I believe $d_3 = -1$ suffices.

Comment: Do you think your problem is with understanding the definitions (eg. of an extreme direction of a set) or with applying the definition to this particular set $S$?

Comment: Definitely more with applying the definition to this particular set $S$. I believe that I understand the basic concept of an extreme direction and can visualize what they are for more basic sets like a simple 2D convex cone.